# C# keystroke interceptor when minimized

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, keyboard-events, keystroke

Ok, so I am trying to write a program that will track my keystrokes while playing a game so that I can analyze the data later to help me improve my game. What I have been trying to do was implement a Global Hotkey Hook using user32.dll's RegisterHotKey. but this captures the keystroke completely, and the game no longer receives the keystroke. I don't know where to go from here and any pointers would be much appreciated. Here is some additional info:

- I am using C#
- .NET 4
- Using Visual Studio 2010
- I am NOT trying to do anything illegal, or against a game TOS

Comment: A search for C# Keyboard Hook should find you plenty of examples. I like [Stephen Toub's example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is taken from Stephan Toubs blog back from 2006:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class InterceptKeys
{
   private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
   private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
   private static LowLevelKeyboardProc _proc = HookCallback;
   private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

   public static void Main()
   {
       _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
       Application.Run();
       UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
   }

   private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelKeyboardProc proc)
   {
       using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
       using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
       {
        return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, proc,
            GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
       }
    }

    private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(
    int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private static IntPtr HookCallback(
    int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   {
       if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
       {
           int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
           Console.WriteLine((Keys)vkCode);
       }

       return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

   [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
   private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,
   LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

   [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
   [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
   private static extern bool  UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

   [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
   private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode,
    IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

   [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
   private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
}
```

Comment: using my google skills I actually came across this myself, but never thought to try it because I thought it was more similar to what I had already tried then what it actually is. I will look it over and give it a shot! I'll let you know how it goes

Comment: Works great for me. I also just recently fiddled around with keyboard hooks for similar reasons and got a similar looking example where it was stated that you must have a windows form just to be able to receive those key strokes, but as it turns out this example demonstrates that you indeed can compile this as a console application, you just need to add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms` and the `Application.Run();` to start the message loop. So no explicit form is needed.

Comment: Ok, so i must sadly admit that because my only form of programming education has been self-taught, i understand very little of that from a first look.... I followed the link, and did as it said and I have 2 problems... If I do it as a Console application (like it says on the website) it has TONS of compile errors. If I do it as a WinForm it compiles after adding "Using System;" to the top, but it does nothing (which i understand it probably wont until i add something else. I just dont know what that something else needs to be... any tips? Thanks again! :)

Comment: @Michael for those errors it would probably be best to just start a new question there, because I was able to just copy paste the code add a reference and it was done (using vs 2012 though), but maybe those errors are trivial enough to be sorted out in the comments? You really need to make it a console application, did you add the reference to `System.Windows.Forms` afterwards (just the reference dont make it a windows forms project)?

Comment: I rescind my previous comment... I figured it out... I just set it up as a plain old class by itself, and added the reference to `System.Windows.Forms` as mentioned by DrCopyPaste it works now!

Comment: @DrCopyPaste thanks again to the both of you! one more quick question, although i will ask it separately as a new question if you think it would be easier, but where should I start if I were to want to (instead of output to console) do something else. or better put, how would be best to use this class with a winforms? sorry if it is a super noob question...

Comment: @Michael should be as easy as `switch outputtype in project's properties to Windows Application`, `add a form to the project` and run that form as a parameter of `Application.Run(new YourFormName())` Or you start a new project as windows forms application and add the same code and include the form into `Application.Run()`

Comment: @DrCopyPaste Ok, so last question... I got the windows form to load up, but like I said before I don't 100% understand each line in the example so I dont know what to change to have it return to me any value that I can use can you point me in the right direction just one more time! ;D   
Thanks again!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51406/discussion-between-drcopypaste-and-michael)